# How to prevent the pop up code from appearing in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans

[image]

As you can see from the image above, every time I put my cursor to the end of curly brace, the related code (i.e. the one appeared on the left side of the image) pops up. This function is helpful when you want to see the beginning of the code snippet, but I don't want it to pop up all the time.

Does anyone know how to turn off this function in NetBeans IDE?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Did you do any configuration after installing NetBeans, or import your settings from another installation of NetBeans? If you have another instance of NetBeans installed, do you see the same problem there as well?

Comment: @skomisa I haven't done any configuration except for some keymap changes, but I don't think modifying keymap affects this function. I downloaded NetBeans from the official site. To be precise, I downloaded a development version of NetBeans that supported Java EE on 1/26/2018.

Comment: OK. You could try downloading a more recent nightly build to see if you can reproduce the problem with that. (It is not a problem to run multiple versions of NetBeans concurrently.) If you can't reproduce the problem on the new instance, try phasing in the keymap changes you have made to see if you can reproduce the problem. You can't lose with that approach; either the new instance works with your all keymap changes so use it, or it breaks in which case you can isolate the specific keymap change that causes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Editor` and select `General` tab and uncheck `Show tooltips`. Click Apply and Ok.